# Picking best combination of items that have target sums

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am creating a Meal Plan Generator (NodeJS/Javascript with MongoDB) that also has a randomized function in it. I have in a MongoDB 400k **Recipe** objects.

**Recipe** object sample:

```
{"name": "Roasted Beef", "calories": 450, "carbs":10 , "fats": 20.2 , "proteins": 55.4}
```

(**Here is a 50 records JSON sample of the Recipes: http://gofile.io/?c=h0xZ5C)**

**(And here is a real JSON dump for over 400k recipes: http://gofile.io/?c=0Utnej You can ignore the "_id" and "_v" fields)**

Say a user needs to generate Meal Plan (a combination of MINIMUM 3 and MAXIMUM 6 **Recipe** objects) to have the following totals (summation of all values in all of its objects) to be each within a target range approximately. But also you can change the **serving_size** of each Recipe, which is a *multiplier* for all of its values, where it could be any value of: **1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 or 4**. This multiplier is needed because we can't find meals that will always match the targets when added, so we need to change the serving size to reach the targets.

Example: Generate a Meal Plan that has:

```
Total calories: 2,000
carbs: [20-50]
fats: [40-70]
proteins: [40-90]
```

So say we do 3 servings of a Recipe, and 2.5 of another, and 1 serving of a third, to reach the target.

I had a solution in mind to iterate over say a set of randomly selected 1,000 Recipes, then try all combinations with various serving_size for each to match the targets. OR a recursive function that picks a random meal, then tries to find another meal and tries to change its serving_size, etc. until we reach the targets.

Meal Plans should be as random as possible, so goal here is not just optimize for the targets but also keep things random as much as possible.

Any known solution to such problem? Just to avoid re-inventing the wheel if any algorithm is known to solve this problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Will calories always be fixed, or is it likely to be expressed as a range constraint as well?

Comment: @ScottSauyetI tried to select Recipes that are all within the desired range +/-8% as margin, which works but very limited options, and repeated most of the time. That's why I decided instead I will need to calculate the total targets in grams then start iterating over the random meals and adjusting serving_size for each to reach the target.

Comment: @ScottSauyet calories always fixed but can have a margin of error no problem.

Comment: Then I would express it like the others, say `[1840-2160]` and embed all error margins in these fixed values.  Otherwise, algorithms would get unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @ScottSauyet ok but my question is which algorithm would best suit this, if anything comes to mind? Any samples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I do think that if you want really random results, then you might just be best off doing some Monte Carlo simulations, or combining that with a logic-programming technique.

Comment: This seems reasonably similar to a [multi-dimensional knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem), but your randomness requirements might make it difficult.  Do you have a small sample set of recipe data available somewhere?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I will send you a JSON dump shortly.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Here it is for over 400k recipes: https://gofile.io/?c=0Utnej
You can ignore the "_id" and "_v" fields.

Comment: That doesn't look like a small subset!  :-)

Comment: I cleaned 80 fields of each record to make the dump even smaller! :)

Comment: Any way you can extract 50 or so and include them in the question?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sure, done and here it is: https://gofile.io/?c=h0xZ5C

Comment: @ScottSauyet if you have any code sample that is relevant I would highly appreciate it. All the knapsack Javascript implementations I am finding online are for 1 variable, couldn't find multi-dimensional ones.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.  I did play with this a little last evening, and while I had a little progress, I didn't get close to solving the problem.  While I find it an interesting challenge, I don't have any particular insights.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm don't know a good algorithm for that. But just a warning for the recursive approach, it should work reasonably well for easy constraints. But when choosing extreme constraints (say we take a recipe in your list which is a pareto minimum, multiply the values by 3 and set them as maximum values, then 3 times the recipe might be the only solution) just trying random combinations can go through an extreme number of combinations.

You should try to limit the options as much as possible without excluding any viable combinations (if you want to retain maximum randomness). If you can make it likely that there is a viable result it can cut down on the recipes that have to be tested (or if the conditions are thorough enough to ensure it you can avoid backtracking entirely). Like for single parameter it is easy: If you have k max for parameter a and start with a recipe that has m in the parameter then min(parameter a)*2+m<=k has to be fulfilled otherwise there can't be a combination including the recipe that can honor the maximum bound. (And for a min of k I suppose m+max(parameter a)*5*4>=k would have to be true, but with the option of going up to 6 recipes and multiplying serving size by up to 4 that should happen less often than violation maxima.)

The tricky part is ensuring that the combination of restrictions can be fulfilled... (Though the single parameter check should serve as a viable first check to lower the numbers of recipes to consider.) I haven't entirely thought this through but for the max part: For it to be fulfill able with the recipe you want to try it has to be fulfill able by adding two recipes, so one of the pareto minima for two recipes has to be able to fulfill it. I think you should get the pareto minima for a combo of two recipes by going through all combinations of pareto minima for a single recipe. I am unsure how many pareto minima will be in the database but if it is a reasonable number you could pre generate the ones for 2 recipes and then try whether there is a pareto minima that when added to the recipe in question would not violate the maximum constraints. (Other way around for the minima but this approach doesn't guarantee that you can fulfill both boundaries at once.)

(Wanted to just write this as comment since it is not much of an answer but it got too long.)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Will research this more.